# PhoneGap - Error occurs when running the example of PhoneGap in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Following this tutorial: [Getting started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).

I try to create my first phonegap project using Eclipse. However, when clicking on the icon of "Cordova Example"(name of the application from the example of PhoneGap) on the screen of device. An error named : "the application Cordova Example (process org.apache.cordova.example) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again" occurs.
This is the log file when error occurs:

```
01-02 09:40:46.280: D/AndroidRuntime(310): Shutting down VM
01-02 09:40:46.280: W/dalvikvm(310): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception                   (group=0x4001d800)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity        ComponentInfo{org.apache.cordova.example/org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample}:    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample in loader    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.apache.cordova.example-2.apk]
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.apache.cordova.example-2.apk]
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
01-02 09:40:46.308: E/AndroidRuntime(310):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.ClassNotFoundException seems like can't find your Main Class, it could be a name problem of your java main class or in config.xml or in manifest, check all names are correctly.

Regards.

Comment: I saw my AndroidManifet.xml and config.xml already. But it seems to be  no wrong of MainClass name of both of these files. :(

Comment: i think this solution can help you: stackoverflow.com/questions/11514193/tip-apache-cordova-and-android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo